# MySQL 5.7 - Unpivoting and flattening a hierarchial dataset with denormalized tables

Tags: mysql, sql, recursion

I have two tables, Appointments (called `SOAppts`) and Procedure Codes (called `SOProccodes`). The Appointments table is part of a dental dataset that contains instructions on procedures to be done to patients. These references are stored in the `SOAppts`.`codeid` columns. There are twenty of these columns (from `codeid1` to `codeid20`), of which five can be seen in the fiddle.

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/9cfef0/2

`codeid` references the `SOProccodes` table which stores actual information about the procedure. A `SOProccodes` table entry consists of the procedure code ID (`proccodeid`), the category (`category`) and the description (`descript`). A `proccodeid` can also consist of references to multiple other procedure codes (hereafter referred to as a multicode).

Multicodes are denoted by a `category` of 999 and entries in the `multicodeXid` columns that can reference other procedure codes or even other multicodes. A multicode can reference up to a mix of 8 procedure codes and/or other multicodes.

Given this information, how can I retrieve the information in such a way that the data is unpivoted (all codeid columns transferred into rows), the hierarchy is flattened and all the procedure codes referenced by the multicodes are seen in a query on the appointments table? I have already attempted to join these tables together, but the fact that a query can easily spiral beyond MySQL's 61-table join limit puts that idea in the trash.

```
apptid  codeid1 codeid2 codeid3 codeid4
22769   1       17      783     725 
22891   1       15      55      679
22892   1       55      58      627
22893   1       783     725     18
```

In this example, apptid 22769 has a multicode of 725.

`select * from SOProccodes where proccodeid = 1, 720, 725`

```
procco descript  category            multinumof multicode1id multicode2id multicode3id multicode4id multicode5id
1      Periodic  1                   0          0            0            0            0            0           
720    Fluoride  2                   0          0            0            0            0            0           
725    Adult Flu 999                 1          720          0            0            0            0
```

I want  `720` to appear instead of `725`, so it would look something like this.

```
apptid  codeid
22769   1       
22769   17
22769   783
22769   720
```

For multicodes that reference other multicodes, I want to output all of these codes in their own rows. For example, appointment 22892:

```
22892   1       55      58      627
```

Has a proccode of 627, which is a multicode that, among the regular procedure codes, references another multicode of 622

`select * from SOProccodes where proccodeid = 627, 622`

```
procco descript           category            multinumof multicode1id multicode2id multicode3id multicode4id multicode5id
622    Cont. Care - Proph 999                 3          54           17           1            0            0           
627    Cont. Care - Compr 999                 5          35           30           33           8            622
```

So, it should look like this (all procedure codes of proccodeid 627 AND all procedure codes of  627's children, 622)

```
apptid    codeid
22892   1       
22892   55      
22892   58      
22892   35           
22892   30           
22892   33           
22892    8   
22892   54
22892   17          
22892   1
```

Comment: While your question itself is a nice one, I am sorry to tell you that both your data model (spreading the information about 20 procedures over 20 columns: why 20 and not 44? (or "1")) and the expected result (returning a basically random number of columns is pretty much useless: image you want to display the procedure text/name instead of a number - what do you join with?) are, frankly, a really bad idea, so the first question would be: are you still able (and open) to change it? Your queries and problems won't get easier once you solve this.

Comment: This database is a component of a widely-used dental software program that was not designed by me, so the data model isn't able to be changed. I am thinking that doing an unpivot operation on this data - turning the appointment `codeid` columns into rows -  combined with a flattening operation of some kind may be more useful. If that were the case, we could just do a single join to the procedure codes table and compare data that way.

Comment: I feared as much as that is a given design. Unpivoting the expected results makes things easier though. Additional things that would make it easier: a) probably not, but can you upgrade to MySQL 8 (allowing recursive ctes)? b) a maximum depth of multicodes (e.g., 622 would not be allowed to have another multicode if it is contained in 627, or could not be assigned to a patient) c) if you don't need it in a single query, but the result of a procedure (then you can put the data in a temp table, add all children, add all childrens children and so on and in the end return the temp table).